# How to combine text columns that sometimes have no values

Tags: sql, group-by

I'm trying to combine column text data that sometimes has no value, but sometimes it does.

```
SELECT RegWOSEGSmry.kserialnum, 
       RegWOSEGSmry.kmodel, 
       RegWOSEGSmry.kmfg, 
       RegWOSEGSmry.kcustnum, 
       RegWOSEGSmry.kbranch, 
       RegWOSEGSmry.kequipnum, 
       RegWOSEGSmry.kworkorder, 
       RegWOSEGSmry.oeshipname, 
       RegWOSEGSmry.oetypeord, 
       RegWOSEGSmry.SourceFlag, 
       RegWOSEGSmry.ardate, 
       RegWOSEGSmry.arinvno, 
       RegWOSEGSmry.aryear, 
       RegWOSEGSmry.CreationDate, 
       RegWOSEGSmry.custpcl, 
       RegWOSEGSmry.custsnum, 
       RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateAll, 
       RegWOSEGSmry.CxOpenDate, 
       RegWOSEGSmry.DistributeFlatRates, 
       RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateLabor,
       RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateMisc,
       RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateParts,

       MAX (RegWOSEGSmry.oeitemlong) as Oeitemlong,

       SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateAllAmt), 
       SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateLaborAmt), 
       SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateMiscAmt),
       SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRatePartsAmt),
       SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.HardwareCost), 
       SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.HardwareStreetPrice), 
       SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.HardwareTMRPrice), 
       SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.LaborCost), 
       SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.LaborStreetPrice), 
       SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.LaborTMRPrice),
       SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.MiscCost),
       SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.MiscStreetPrice), 
       SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.MiscTMRPrice), 
       SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.PartsCost), 
       SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.PartsStreetPrice), 
       SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.PartsTMRPrice), 
       SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.TaxCost), 
       SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.TaxStreetPrice),
       SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.TaxTMRPrice),
       SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.LaborHours), 

       AVG (RegWOSEGSmry.artotal)

FROM WieseData.dbo.RegWOSEGSmry RegWOSEGSmry

WHERE (RegWOSEGSmry.kcustnum='165453')

GROUP BY RegWOSEGSmry.kserialnum, 
         RegWOSEGSmry.kmodel, 
         RegWOSEGSmry.kmfg, 
         RegWOSEGSmry.kcustnum, 
         RegWOSEGSmry.kbranch, 
         RegWOSEGSmry.kequipnum, 
         RegWOSEGSmry.kworkorder, 
         RegWOSEGSmry.oeshipname, 
         RegWOSEGSmry.oetypeord, 
         RegWOSEGSmry.SourceFlag, 
         RegWOSEGSmry.ardate, 
         RegWOSEGSmry.arinvno, 
         RegWOSEGSmry.aryear, 
         RegWOSEGSmry.CreationDate, 
         RegWOSEGSmry.custpcl, 
         RegWOSEGSmry.custsnum, 
         RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateAll, 
         RegWOSEGSmry.CxOpenDate, 
         RegWOSEGSmry.DistributeFlatRates, 
         RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateLabor,
         RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateMisc,
         RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateParts
```

Which produces this:
[image]

I need to have the "Kserialnum", "Kmodel", and "Kequipmnum" combined, but sometimes as the picture shows, there's no value to "Group By".

Comment: You can return a default value when a column contains a NULL. What's your platform?

Comment: MY Sql is the platform

Answer (score 2):

Combined as in concatenated in some way? The null values aren't a problem unless you are on a platform where string concatenation returns null on any null input. i.e. `SELECT 'A' + NULL + 'C'` would return `NULL`. In this case:

```
COALESCE(RegWOSEGSmry.kserialnum, '')
+ COALESCE(RegWOSEGSmry.kmodel, '')
+ COALESCE(RegWOSEGSmry.kequipnum, '')
```

This is a valid way to concatenate them for SQL Server, or replace `+` with `||` and `COALESCE` with `NVL` for Oracle. This can be used in both the select and group by clauses.

Comment: Yes, combined in some way so that everything is returned on one line.  Is the "Coalesce" function added to the "Group By" function at the end of the query, or is it added to it as well?

Comment: Could be, but not required in your current setup.

Comment: SELECT 
RegWOSEGSmry.kworkorder, 
RegWOSEGSmry.kcustnum, 
RegWOSEGSmry.kbranch, 
RegWOSEGSmry.oeshipname, 
RegWOSEGSmry.oetypeord, 
RegWOSEGSmry.SourceFlag, 
RegWOSEGSmry.ardate, 
RegWOSEGSmry.arinvno, 
RegWOSEGSmry.aryear, 
RegWOSEGSmry.CreationDate, 
RegWOSEGSmry.custpcl, 
RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateMisc,
RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateParts,
COALESCE(RegWOSEGSmry.kserialnum)
COALESCE(RegWOSEGSmry.kmodel)
COALESCE(RegWOSEGSmry.kmfg)
COALESCE(RegWOSEGSmry.kequipnum)

MAX (RegWOSEGSmry.oeitemlong) as Oeitemlong,

Comment: You need to use the `+` or `||` concatenate operators between the coalesce commands, depending on the DBMS, as I mentioned.

Comment: I probably didn't explain clearly, but I don't need to concatenate multiple columns into one cell, I just need to "collapse" the column that doesn't have data into the cell underneath it/above it that actually has data.

Comment: There are differentiators in the column values, then. The reason There are 3 rows in your screenshot is that there is something different in all 3 from one another in any column from kserialnum to FlatRateParts. If the data is identical, those rows get passed into the aggregate functions and grouped per the group by clause. This is how SQL works. If you alter your question to include sample data and intended output, perhaps a solution can be found.

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM WieseData.dbo.RegWOSEGSmry RegWOSEGSmry

WHERE (RegWOSEGSmry.kcustnum='165453')
and ( "Kserialnum" is not null
and  "Kmodel" is not null
and "Kequipmnum" is not null)
```

Looks like you want data for not nulls only. just add above condition after where clause. Let me know if you are looking for something else.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'd actually like to combine the rows/columns that have no data into one line.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can replace NULL values with a default value using the `IFNULL` function, usage `IFNULL(columnName, defaultValue)`.

Since you're getting NULL values in three of your columns, apply the function on these columns. Considering a default value `123`, your query becomes the following:

```
SELECT IFNULL(RegWOSEGSmry.kserialnum, 123), 
   IFNULL(RegWOSEGSmry.kmodel, 123), 
   RegWOSEGSmry.kmfg, 
   RegWOSEGSmry.kcustnum, 
   RegWOSEGSmry.kbranch, 
   IFNULL(RegWOSEGSmry.kequipnum, 123), 
   RegWOSEGSmry.kworkorder, 
   RegWOSEGSmry.oeshipname, 
   RegWOSEGSmry.oetypeord, 
   RegWOSEGSmry.SourceFlag, 
   RegWOSEGSmry.ardate, 
   RegWOSEGSmry.arinvno, 
   RegWOSEGSmry.aryear, 
   RegWOSEGSmry.CreationDate, 
   RegWOSEGSmry.custpcl, 
   RegWOSEGSmry.custsnum, 
   RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateAll, 
   RegWOSEGSmry.CxOpenDate, 
   RegWOSEGSmry.DistributeFlatRates, 
   RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateLabor,
   RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateMisc,
   RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateParts,

   MAX (RegWOSEGSmry.oeitemlong) as Oeitemlong,

   SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateAllAmt), 
   SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateLaborAmt), 
   SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateMiscAmt),
   SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRatePartsAmt),
   SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.HardwareCost), 
   SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.HardwareStreetPrice), 
   SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.HardwareTMRPrice), 
   SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.LaborCost), 
   SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.LaborStreetPrice), 
   SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.LaborTMRPrice),
   SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.MiscCost),
   SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.MiscStreetPrice), 
   SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.MiscTMRPrice), 
   SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.PartsCost), 
   SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.PartsStreetPrice), 
   SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.PartsTMRPrice), 
   SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.TaxCost), 
   SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.TaxStreetPrice),
   SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.TaxTMRPrice),
   SUM (RegWOSEGSmry.LaborHours), 

   AVG (RegWOSEGSmry.artotal)

FROM WieseData.dbo.RegWOSEGSmry RegWOSEGSmry

WHERE (RegWOSEGSmry.kcustnum='165453')

GROUP BY IFNULL(RegWOSEGSmry.kserialnum, 123), 
     IFNULL(RegWOSEGSmry.kmodel, 123), 
     RegWOSEGSmry.kmfg, 
     RegWOSEGSmry.kcustnum, 
     RegWOSEGSmry.kbranch, 
     IFNULL(RegWOSEGSmry.kequipnum, 123), 
     RegWOSEGSmry.kworkorder, 
     RegWOSEGSmry.oeshipname, 
     RegWOSEGSmry.oetypeord, 
     RegWOSEGSmry.SourceFlag, 
     RegWOSEGSmry.ardate, 
     RegWOSEGSmry.arinvno, 
     RegWOSEGSmry.aryear, 
     RegWOSEGSmry.CreationDate, 
     RegWOSEGSmry.custpcl, 
     RegWOSEGSmry.custsnum, 
     RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateAll, 
     RegWOSEGSmry.CxOpenDate, 
     RegWOSEGSmry.DistributeFlatRates, 
     RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateLabor,
     RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateMisc,
     RegWOSEGSmry.FlatRateParts
```

Now whenever a column contains a **NULL**, **123** is returned instead.